# CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged doesn't work after a datagridview error C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview where I load data from a database. That datagridview has 2 int columns where I insert numbers. And, If I insert a number in one of the two columns, there are another two columns cells that fill automaticaly with a result of a mathematical operation. On the contrary, if I insert a letter the datagridview shows me an error.

the problen is this: whenever the datagridview shows me an error, after clicking "OK" in the error messagebox, I can keep editing the cell but CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event doesn't work. Therefore the other two columns cells don't fill automaticaly. And I need them to fill automaticaly after the error is shown.

this is my code:

```
private void dgvReciboPagoSalario_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)

    {
        e.ThrowException = false;

        string Error = "Error: La columna " +
            dgvReciboPagoSalario.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText +
            " es de tipo numérico";

        DialogResult DR= MessageBox.Show(Error, "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        e.Cancel = false;
    }
```

this is the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event:

```
private void dgvReciboPagoSalario_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//modificar campos de dgv al mismo tiempo que cambio otro
        int HO = 0;
        int HF = 0;
        long SXH = 0;
        long Subtotal = 0;
        long DeduccionesPrestamo = 0;
        long DeduccionesCCSS = 0;
        long Total = 0;

        if (dgvReciboPagoSalario.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {


            dgvReciboPagoSalario.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgvReciboPagoSalario.CurrentRow.Cells["Horas Ordinarias"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                HO = Convert.ToInt32(dgvReciboPagoSalario.CurrentRow.Cells["Horas Ordinarias"].Value);
            }


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgvReciboPagoSalario.CurrentRow.Cells["Horas Feriado"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                HF = Convert.ToInt32(dgvReciboPagoSalario.CurrentRow.Cells["Horas Feriado"].Value);
            }

            SXH = Convert.ToInt64(dgvReciboPagoSalario.CurrentRow.Cells["Salario por Hora"].Value);

            Subtotal = ((HO * SXH) + ((SXH * 2) * HF));

            dgvReciboPagoSalario.CurrentRow.Cells["Subtotal Recibido"].Value = Subtotal;


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgvReciboPagoSalario.CurrentRow.Cells["Deducciones Préstamo"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                DeduccionesPrestamo = Convert.ToInt64(dgvReciboPagoSalario.CurrentRow.Cells["Deducciones Préstamo"].Value);
            }

            DeduccionesCCSS = Convert.ToInt64(dgvReciboPagoSalario.CurrentRow.Cells["Deducciones CCSS"].Value);

            Total = (Subtotal - (DeduccionesCCSS + DeduccionesPrestamo));

            dgvReciboPagoSalario.CurrentRow.Cells["Total Recibido"].Value = Total;                               
        }
```

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the posted code, it appears it is setting the `Total Recibido` column from the values in the other columns using the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event. This will work, however if you were to use a `DataTable` and set the `Total Recibido` column to be an `Expression` of the current cells in the table, then there will be no need for the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event to handle this.

Example, following the posted code and using a `DataTable` a possible `Expression` for the `Total Recibido` column could be something like below. The last column added is the `Expression` for the `Total` column.

```
private DataTable GetDT() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("OrdinaryHours", typeof(double));
  dt.Columns.Add("HourlyWage", typeof(double));
  dt.Columns.Add("HolidayHours", typeof(double));
  dt.Columns.Add("CCSSDeductions", typeof(double));
  dt.Columns.Add("LoanDeductions", typeof(double));
  DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Total", typeof(double));
  dc.Expression = "((OrdinaryHours * HourlyWage) + (HourlyWage * 2) * HolidayHours) - (CCSSDeductions + LoanDeductions)";
  dt.Columns.Add(dc);
  return dt;
}
```

Using the above `DataTable` with an `Expression` column for the `Total`s will eliminate the need for the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event. The `Total`s column cells will be automatically updated after all the other cells have data.

In addition, from the post it appears that you are NOT catching this `DataError` which is a problem IMHO. Since the columns in question are of numeric types (int, double..etc) then the `DataError` will be thrown when the user types characters instead of numbers and tries to leave the cell.

I am guessing it may be easier and more user friendly if you “catch” the users `KeyPressed` event and simply ignore any invalid characters. Example: if you catch the users `KeyPressed` input and it is in one of the columns that should be a number AND it is not a number or a decimal point then ignore the input. With this implementation, the user will not be able to type in characters other than numbers and a decimal point. This will prevent the `DataError` from getting thrown for those columns.

In order to accomplish this, you need to implement a “KeyPressed” event for the cells in the target columns. When this event fires, it can check and ignore any invalid characters. The event that needs to be wired up is the `DataGridViews` `EditingControlShowing` event. This event will fire when the user types into a cell. First, a check is made to see if the cell the user typed into is in one of the columns that is a number column. If it is, then you simply need to register the `KeyPressed` event to that cell. Then the `KeyPressed` event will be fired and you can check for the proper character values.

Below is an example of what this `KeyPressed` event may look like.

```
private void DoubleColumn_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  // if the key pressed is not a control key or a digit or decimal - then ignore this character
  if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.') {
    e.Handled = true;
  }
  // check for multiple decimal points as only one is valid
  if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1) {
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Then to use this event, we simply register the event with the cell when the user types into a numeric column cell. The event for this is the `EditingControlShowing` event. In this event a check is made to see if it is a number column then register the `KeyPressed` event to fire for that cell.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) {
  e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(DoubleColumn_KeyPress);
  if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 || dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2 ||
      dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3 || dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4 ||
      dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5) {
    e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(DoubleColumn_KeyPress);
  }
}
```

The above two methods should work regardless if the `DataGridView` is data bound or not. Hope this helps.